# Folder created with Docker RUN command keeps disappearing

Tags: docker, dockerfile

## Dockerfile contents:

```
# Setup directory structure
RUN mkdir -p /dev/log/ \
 && touch /dev/log/placeholder.file \
 && ls -la /dev/
```

As you can see below, the `/dev/log/` folder is conspicuously missing from the actual container after being visible in the `docker build` output. Where is it going? Is `/dev/` considered a special folder?

## `docker build` output:

```
Step 13/14 : RUN mkdir -p /dev/log/  && touch /dev/log/placeholder.file  && ls -la /dev/
 ---> Running in ac5014b75a54
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  360 Oct 17 15:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 17 15:04 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   11 Oct 17 15:04 core -> /proc/kcore
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13 Oct 17 15:04 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 7 Oct 17 15:04 full
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   60 Oct 17 15:04 log
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root   40 Oct 17 15:04 mqueue
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Oct 17 15:04 null
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    8 Oct 17 15:04 ptmx -> pts/ptmx
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Oct 17 15:04 pts
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 8 Oct 17 15:04 random
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root   40 Oct 17 15:04 shm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Oct 17 15:04 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Oct 17 15:04 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Oct 17 15:04 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 0 Oct 17 15:04 tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 9 Oct 17 15:04 urandom
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 5 Oct 17 15:04 zero
 ---> 2bdcd739e2c7
Removing intermediate container ac5014b75a54
```

## View from inside the container:

`docker run -it --rm <container> /bin/bash`

```
[root@moby dev]# ls -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    360 Oct 17 15:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Oct 17 15:19 ..
crw--w---- 1 root tty  136, 0 Oct 17  2017 console
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     11 Oct 17 15:19 core -> /proc/kcore
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 Oct 17 15:19 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1, 7 Oct 17 15:19 full
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root     40 Oct 17 15:19 mqueue
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1, 3 Oct 17 15:19 null
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Oct 17 15:19 ptmx -> pts/ptmx
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      0 Oct 17 15:19 pts
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1, 8 Oct 17 15:19 random
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root     40 Oct 17 15:19 shm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Oct 17 15:19 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Oct 17 15:19 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Oct 17 15:19 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   5, 0 Oct 17 15:19 tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1, 9 Oct 17 15:19 urandom
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1, 5 Oct 17 15:19 zero
```

Comment: Don't use `/dev` as parent directory.

Comment: I don't have a choice, it is required by a library being installed in the container. If `/dev/log/` is unavailable then it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is /dev/ considered a special folder?

Short answer, yes. It is a special folder and you shouldn't store stuff there. What is happening is that `/dev` gets mounted at container runtime, which is overwriting your folder:

```
$ docker run ubuntu mount | grep "/dev"
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
```

You will need to choose another place to store files or create the folder at runtime so that it happens after the mount.

Comment: I don't have a choice about whether or not to use `/dev`, but it sounds like I need to create the folder with the Dockerfile `CMD` keyword.

Comment: Correct. You could also create an `ENTRYPOINT` script that creates the folder and then runs anything from `CMD`.